# sum two alias in linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

i write this query in linq and i want to do this work
1-sum x and y in select new 
2-minus timespans and multiplay in a number for example 30

```
var query = 
    (from c in DB.SabtHoghoghs
     join aa in DB.SabtHesabKarmands on c.KarmandID equals aa.KarmandID
     select new 
        { 
            c.Karmand.FName,
            c.BabatMah,
            x = DB.SabtHesabKarmands.Where(q => q.BabatMah.Year == c.BabatMah.Year &&
                q.BabatMah.Month == c.BabatMah.Month && q.HesabKarmand.HesabKarmandTypeID==1)
                .Sum(aaa => aaa.Tedad * aaa.HesabKarmand.Mablagh),

            y = DB.SabtHesabKarmands.Where(q => q.BabatMah.Year == c.BabatMah.Year &&
                q.BabatMah.Month == c.BabatMah.Month && q.HesabKarmand.HesabKarmandTypeID == 2)
                .Sum(aaa => aaa.Tedad * aaa.HesabKarmand.Mablagh),

            z=y-x   //how to do this(1)

            karkard = (c.Karmand.ExitTime-c.Karmand.EnterTime).Hours *30  //how to do this(2)

        }).Distinct();
```

Comment: This looks like a magic spell.

Comment: @AlexanderTsvetkov It's strange how often OPs spend no time formatting code...

Comment: What `ORM` do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `let` keyword in your query:

```
var query =
(from c in DB.SabtHoghoghs
join aa in DB.SabtHesabKarmands on c.KarmandID equals aa.KarmandID
let x = DB.SabtHesabKarmands.Where(q => q.BabatMah.Year == c.BabatMah.Year &&
        q.BabatMah.Month == c.BabatMah.Month && q.HesabKarmand.HesabKarmandTypeID == 1)
        .Sum(aaa => aaa.Tedad * aaa.HesabKarmand.Mablagh)
let y = DB.SabtHesabKarmands.Where(q => q.BabatMah.Year == c.BabatMah.Year &&
        q.BabatMah.Month == c.BabatMah.Month && q.HesabKarmand.HesabKarmandTypeID == 2)
        .Sum(aaa => aaa.Tedad * aaa.HesabKarmand.Mablagh)
select new
{
    c.Karmand.FName,
    c.BabatMah,

    X = x,
    Y = y,

    Z = y - x,   //how to do this(1)

    karkard = (c.Karmand.ExitTime - c.Karmand.EnterTime).Hours * 30  //how to do this(2)

}).Distinct();
```

Comment: tnx let work but how about the second problem: i have two field type time(7) in sql and in linq as u know is timespan.i want minus them and multiplay to a number for example 30

Comment: In (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882662.aspx) : Although the CLR System.TimeSpan type does support addition and subtraction, the SQL TIME type does not. Because of this, your LINQ to SQL queries will generate errors if they attempt addition and subtraction when they are mapped to the SQL TIME type. You can find other considerations for working with SQL date and time types in SQL-CLR Type Mapping.

Comment: Maybe you can try a different mapping for Time : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx#BehaviorMatrix

Answer (score 0):

I will try to direct you to the correct solution. 
Define your custom class, don't use anonymous classes, like so

```
class MyClass
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string BabatMah { get; set; }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public int z { get { return x - y; }    }

    public int karkard { get; set; }

    // implement Equals and GetHashCode for correct behaviour of Distinct
}
```

And then just select computational values without `z` into `MyClass`

```
select new MyClass
    { 
        FName = c.Karmand.FName,
        BabatMah = c.BabatMah,
        ...
```

In order to resolve `(c.Karmand.ExitTime-c.Karmand.EnterTime).Hours *30` calculation, you need to bring more details regarding your ORM. The solution will depend. One general solution is to extract `ExitTime` and `EnterTime` into `MyClass` and then calculate difference in hours the same way, as you calculated `x - y`

Comment: tnx it is good idea but how about the second question: i have two field type time(7) in sql and in linq as u know is timespan.i want minus them and multiplay to a number for example 30 on this line `karkard = (c.Karmand.ExitTime-c.Karmand.EnterTime).Hours *30 ` Error: **'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Hours' and no extension method 'Hours' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**